# Colorize function not working after updating 2D Array

Tags: angularjs, function, matrix

I am using a duo of ng-repeat's to create a matrix table, but after updating the data the coloring function (a simple return 'green' if the argument is above 0) stops working.

When I load the first (fake) data the colors work just fine, but after any updates it stops working. When initializing the 2d array it will always load and display properly. I have found no debug errors or problem with the logic.

[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wubhnsjc/4/)
UPDATE**: I created a simple function that changes a few values in the 'original' 2D-array and I still face the problem with it not updating colors. I am pretty positive this is an AngularJS problem (shortcoming?) and not an issue with the data itself.

## HTML

```
<!-- MATRIX TABLE -->
    <div class="center w80" >
        <div id = "MatrixTable2">
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th> <!-- blank -->
                        <th ng-repeat="ppp in PlayerIDList">{{ppp.name}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr width="50px" ng-repeat="row in Matrix" >
                        <td class="rowlabel">{{PlayerIDList[$index].name}}</td>
                        <td width="50px" ng-repeat="col in row track by $index" ng-class="::funcGetColorByBool({{col}})">{{col}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- END MATRIX TABLE -->
```

Comment: Could you please add your js code to your question? Also a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) to show the issue would be great.

Comment: There are pages of code that doesn't affect the problem. I monitored the data and data type going into the funcGetColorByBool() function and they are identical before and after updating the actual values. It simply seems that the page isn't updating, as opposed to any traditional defect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is the class binding, the `::` prefix means this expression is only evaluated once.

```
"::funcGetColorByBool({{col}})"
```

Also, you need to fix your expression to pass in the value of col:

**from:**

```
ng-class="::funcGetColorByBool({{col}})"
```

**to:**

```
ng-class="funcGetColorByBool(col)"
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/I3Kbpc8QfxtHTV4mzwNE?p=preview) is a working plunker.

Comment: I use the same style of function call in my other angular projects and they update just fine. I did however try without :: and the problem still persists. Sad.

Comment: ng-class accepts an expression. So you don't (and shouldn't) need the {{binding} syntax.

Comment: AH! you've clarified it for me. Thanks

Comment: Updated link to Plunker